# Ion-input file component not allowed on StencilJS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, stenciljs

I'm using some ionic components inside a stenciljs project and some of them gives me errors also if I follow the documentation.

For example, `<ion-input type="file"></ion-input>` gives me this error **"Type '"file"' is not assignable to type 'TextFieldTypes'."**

This happens despite the fact that the ionic documentation allow to give to a ion-input the type=file.

I've tried also`<ion-input file />` I have another error **"Type '{ file: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IonInput'.**
**  Property 'file' does not exist on type 'IonInput'".**

I don't understand how to use a simple ion-input field with type file.

Answer (score 2):

This is because its not an option:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/interface.d.ts#L40

Shows:

```
export type TextFieldTypes = 'date' | 'email' | 'number' | 'password' | 'search' | 'tel' | 'text' | 'url' | 'time';
```

If you want to handle files you need to interface with the filesystem on mobile so it needs an Ionic Native plugin to bridge this:

[File - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

At the time of writing, the documentation does make reference to the `file` parameter in multiple locations but the Ionic Team [have confirmed](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/issues/814#issuecomment-509687038) this is a mistake with the documentation, not a missing feature of `ion-input`.

Comment: Yes, had the same problem. Just use html5 <input> to collect a file.

Comment: but in the Properties section, in the accept paragraph it's written:
"If the value of the type attribute is "file", then this attribute will indicate the types of files that the server accepts, otherwise it will be ignored."
Reading this suggests that it is possible to use the "file" type as an ion-input type... so I guess that the documentation it's not clear about that... I don't know why this is written if is not possible to use type=file

Comment: That, my friend, is an excellent point, and you appear to have found a bug in Ionic Core. I have [opened a support ticket with the team](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18741)

Comment: Update: they have replied and said its an issue with the docs, not the code. It shouldn't mention `file` as a possibility.